# sql server management studio invalid column name where clause

Tags: sql, ssms

I am writing a query to filter a table by a certain field. However, the filter I am using is being evaluated as a column for some unknown reason.

i.e.

```
SELECT prn FROM CompanyPack WHERE prn = "212"
```

In this query, SSMS 2012 throws an error in which it is telling me that "212" is an invalid column name, but it is not a column at all.

```
prn is a nvarchar(50).
```

Any advice?

Comment: use single quote = '212'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use single quotes `'`' not double quotes `"`. Like so

```
SELECT prn FROM CompanyPack WHERE prn = '212'
```